# jQuery - Counting table rows not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm coding an application that adds rows to a table without refresh using javascript and jquery. In order to append to the table, I need to do a count of the rows that are currently in the table. I'm using this code...

```
var count = $('#columns tr.FIELD').length;
```

The code works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but I am required to build around IE7. Is there any reason that IE returns a count of 0 while this selector works fine in other browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: After revisiting this question I decided to write a small, [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sHH2n/) for you, using the exact same selector.  I think you might have to post your html markup so we might be able to properly identify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think IE7 might be inserting a hidden `tbody` tag in your table, which causes the selector to be incorrect.

Try `$('#columns').find('tr.FIELD').length`

More appropriately, make sure your table is semantically correct

```
<table>
<thead>[HEADER ROW]</thead>
<tbody>[CONTENT]</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 - To simplify my life I use tbody tags in tables now, just to keep it consistent with IE. :)

Comment: This bit me the first time I built an incorrect table and needed to parse over it in IE. I was building the tables dynamically, which caused all kinds of headaches with the auto-table-building :P.

Comment: IE isn't the only browser that inserts the TBODY element.  **All** the major browsers, including Firefox and Chrome, do the same thing.  Try it yourself in the console - `var d = document.createElement("div"); d.innerHTML = "<table><tr></tr></table>"; alert(d.innerHTML);`. Also, there's no `>` selector in the OP's question, so even with the TBODY element all TRs would be returned (the OP specifically states that IE7 returns 0 rows).